# force python to use my downloaded (to path : /home/pytlib) Paramiko library

Tags: python

could you help me with followings.
paramiko 16.1.0 library is in [python default] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
But I can not upgrade paramiko 16.1.0 library to current paramiko 2.8.0 library; so I had to download paramiko 2.8.0 library into my path /home/pylib
Please let me know how I can force python to use /home/pylib/paramiko [paramiko 2.8.0 library] in my python code
Note: for now I am stuck with Python 2.7;I can not update PYTHONPATH

Comment: You can do this with importlib but you probably shouldn't. It would be better to create a userspace venv.

Comment: @CJR Thanks. user would not allow any download as their server has firewall; so I would have to give user with tar ball my code and dependencies. user would not be able to download venv or virtualenv, tried to use importlib no luck

Comment: Stick the paramiko python package into your package and relative import it. Or have the user get the paramiko repo and run setup.py to put it into the userspace python library. Or use importlib. Whatever choices brought you to these options were the wrong choices and you should consider going back to make better ones.

Comment: @CJR Thanks. I did followings. Please let know if it is ok--- code
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/pylib')
import paramiko

print ">>> paramiko version =",paramiko.__version__

Result:
>>> paramiko version = 2.8.1
--- code
import sys
#sys.path.insert(0,'/home/pylib')
import paramiko

print ">>> paramiko version =",paramiko.__version__

Result:
>>> paramiko version = 1.16.0 - default version from installed python

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to use virtual environments to avoid conflicts like this.

### What is a virtual environment?

A virtual environment is basically like creating a fresh installation of Python for only one project. This allows you to easily have two different versions of a library installed for different projects.

### How do I use virtual environments?

Install the `virtualenv` package: `pip2 install virtualenv`

Go to the root of your project `cd path/to/project/root`

Create a virtualenv: `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 venv`

Activate the environment: `. venv/bin/activate`

Install the package version you want: `pip2 install paramiko==2.8.0`

Run your program: `python something.py`

To exit the virtual environment use: `deactivate`

Next time you want to run your program make sure you activate the environment with `. venv/bin/activate` first. None of the other steps need to be repeated.